# java spring problem : server can not start because of "SEVERE: A child container failed during start..."?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am studying java spring boot and here is my problem.

I decided to reorganize my files like this

```
/layouts/user/footer.jsp
/layouts/user/header.jsp
/layouts/user.jsp
/user/index.jsp
/web.xml
```

From the user.jsp file, I wrote this code to link to the footer.jsp and the header.jsp file

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/layouts/user/header.jsp"%>
<decorator:body />
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/layouts/user/footer.jsp"%>
```

Then I ran my code by tomcat 9.0.62 and got this error

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/DemoSpringMVC]]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/DemoSpringMVC]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name [sitemesh]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3067)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3029)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1453)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1329)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:986)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 27 more
thg 12 18, 2022 4:56:35 CH org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/DemoSpringMVC]]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/DemoSpringMVC]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name [sitemesh]
at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3067)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3029)
at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1453)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1329)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:986)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 27 more
```

I tried to install tomcat 8.5 and tomcat 10 and still meet the same error, so maybe it is not because of tomcat version.

I also reference this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYMrMAi95YU, but in my code I had changed the code to url-pattern so it is not the reason.

Here is my code, if you need

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/Spring3.2
```

Could you please give me some advices for this problem ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You've named both filter and servlet as "demo-config". Just update the filter name (observe value in `filter-name` tag)

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter
        </filter-class>
        <!-- Added the context configuration below -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/demo-config-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to pay attention to the output exception stack first. It mentioned the root cause already.

> i.e. `*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name [sitemesh]*`

If you are setting up a new web application, I'll suggest you make it as simple as possible as well. So, remove those filters you do not need.

If your web application was running successfully before, then please focus on your new changes, especially regarding above filter.

After checking your code in the GitHub, I feel you need to set up the filter `sitemesh` with the same name in both section `filter` and **filter-mapping**, otherwise, the filter-mapping will not understand where the filter instance is. Please try following configuration. Note: Based on your `web.xml` file, I changed the value of **filter-name** to **sitemesh** from **demo-config**.

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter
        </filter-class>
        <!-- Added the context configuration below -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/demo-config-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </filter>

    <!-- Mapped the servlet to '/' -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```